# Regular Expression: return everything in a line prior to the second tab occurence

Tags: regex, python-3.x, file, parsing

I have a corpus file that is containing data in the following format:

```
Hi.   bonjour.  CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #629296 (Samer)
black!  noir!   CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #906328 (papabear) & #1245450 (saeb)
```

Essentially spllited into three fields with \t. e.g:

**Hi** \t **bonjour** \t **CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #629296 (Samer)**

I'm trying to only get the key:value:

```
Hi.   bonjour.
black!  noir!
```

and avoid everything else that comes next.
This is how I used to do it before the extra metadata was added following the key:value:

```
def load_doc(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, "r+", "utf-8") as file:
        file = file.read()
        return file


def to_pairs(doc):
    lines = doc.strip().split('\n')
    pairs = [line.split('\t') for line in  lines]
    return pairs

pairs = to_pairs(load_doc(filename))
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: You could do it with a regex pattern using capturing groups, but why don't you just modify the current code so after `pairs = [line.split('\t') for line in  lines]` just return a new array with paris[0] and pairs[1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 negated character classes and 2 capturing groups.

```
^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)
```

- `^` Start of string (can be omitted using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match))
- `([^\t]+)` Capture **group 1** Match any char except a tab
- `\t` Match a tab
- `([^\t]+)` Capture **group 2** Match any char except a tab

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JdSEQq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0dngHi)

If you don't want to cross a newline, you could add that to the character class `[^\t\r\n]`

For example:

```
import re

doc = ("Hi. bonjour.    CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #629296 (Samer)\n"
            "black! noir!   CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #906328 (papabear) & #1245450 (saeb)")

lines = doc.strip().split('\n')
pairs = [re.match(r"([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)", line).groups() for line in lines]
print (pairs)
```

Output

```
[('Hi.', 'bonjour.'), ('black!', 'noir!')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
import re

lines = [
    'Hi.\tbonjour.\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #629296 (Samer)',
    'black!\tnoir!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #906328 (papabear) & #1245450 (saeb)',
]

for line in lines:
    pairs = re.search(r'^(.+?)\t(.+?)(?=\t)', line)
    print(pairs.groups())

    #added parentheses to built-in method 'print' OP Python v3+
```

**Output:**

```
('Hi.', 'bonjour.')
('black!', 'noir!')
```